# Cancelling Facebook Share does not produce error response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I click the share button that I created on my page, then get taken to https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/share... and click "Cancel", the `response` is an empty array, `[]`.

I get the same response, an empty array, `[]`, when clicking "Share" and actually share the link. If this is the expected behaviour, how can I differentiate between someone clicking "Share" and "Cancel"? I would like to know if the Share is actually shared and not cancelled.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: url
}, function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
        console.log('Posting completed.');
    } else {
        console.log('Error while posting.');
    }
});
```

Comment: You’ll only get a response from the Share dialog, if the user is logged in to your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response – _“I would like to know if the Share is actually shared and not cancelled”_ – in case your interest in that is because you want to reward users for sharing, or keep content hidden from them if they don’t share, be advised that this is against Platform Policy. You are not allowed to do that.

Comment: Just trying to keep analytics on the sharing, that's all. Thanks for the help though.